# Pendrive without any partitions on it

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I got a pendrive with only partition table on it (lsblk outputs /dev/sdc, but not /dev/sdc1). Is it fully safe just to create partition on it and format it?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Are there data of any value on it? If not, what could you possibly be fearing?

Comment: "Are there data of any value on it?"
No.
"If not, what could you possibly be fearing?"
Possibly nothing. But I wasn't sure, so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe. You can further check for partitions with

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdc
```